# typing: type hinting when function returns tuple with unpacked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking, python-typing

I have this:

```
from typing import Tuple
import random

a = random.randint(100) # some random number

def foo(a: int) -> Tuple:
    b = []
    for _ in random.randint(0, 10):
       b.append(random.randint(-5, 5) # adding random numbers to b
    return a, *b
```

And I want to write **return type** for this function, but I don't now how to do this *properly*:

I tried this:

```
from typing import Tuple
import random

a = random.randint(100) # some random number. It doesn't matter

def foo(a: int) -> Tuple[int, *Tuple[int, ...]]:
    b = []
    for _ in random.randint(0, 10):
       b.append(random.randint(-5, 5) # adding random numbers to b
    return a, *b
```

**Pycharm** with **mypy** says: `foo(a: int) -> Tuple[int, Any]`
But I need the function to return the type of variable that was passed to it

In a *real project*, it takes a **generic** and returns a **tuple** with the object and the **unpacked list** in it for readability

Real function:

```
...
    def get_entities_with(self, *component_types):
        for entity in self.entities.values():
            require_components = [component for component in entity.components if type(component) in component_types]
            if len(require_components) == len(component_types):
                yield entity, *require_components
...
```

.pyi File:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
...
    def get_entities_with(self, *components:Type[T]) -> Generator[Entity, *Tuple[T, ...]]: ...
```

Comment: `a, *b` is just `Tuple[int, ...]`

Comment: I don’t think Python typings support `Tuple[Entity, T, ...]`.

Comment: Can you change your code to return `entity, require_components` instead?

Comment: @Georgy Yes, I can, but I'm interesting in this issue, when u need return unpacked iterable in tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python **3.11** or above, you can simply use the unpack asterisk (`*`) in the type hint for the return type, similar to the way you wrote it in your question (but slightly different, see example below).

But since, as of the time of writing, Python 3.11 is still not public your are likely using a version **3.10 or earlier**. If this is the case you can use the backported special type `Unpack`, that is available in `typing_extensions`, available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).

**Example usage:**

```
from typing_extensions import Unpack

# Python <=3.10
def unpack_hints_py_10_and_below(args: list[str]) -> tuple[int, Unpack[str]]:
    first_arg, *rest = args
    return len(first_arg), *rest

# Python >= 3.11
def unpack_hints_py_11_and_above(args: list[str]) -> tuple[int, *str]:
    first_arg, *rest = args
    return len(first_arg), *rest
```

**Further (heavy) Reading:** see [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/).

Happy typing!